# Python - Pass default values for arguments that are function of other arguments of the function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I would like to write a function in which the default value of one argument is a function of some arguments that are being passed to the same function. Something like this:

```
def function(x, y = function2(x)):
    ##definition of the function
```

Is it possible to write such a function in Python?
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978790/how-to-give-an-argument-a-default-value-determined-by-a-function-of-the-other-ar) answer for c++. But there is no method overloading in Python

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pretty usual way of solving this is by using `None` as a placeholder:

```
def function(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = f2(x)

    pass  # whatever function() needs to do
```

Comment: Also, this would be the best way of setting default values for some mutabe typed variable.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. hat are you trying to achieve? What is the Y? Is taht function? then you must write:

```
def function(x, y = function2):
    ##definition of the function
```

If the Y is a simple value then you must write:

```
def function(x, y = None):
    if y is None:
         y = function2(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve here use case wise but you can use a decorator that does what is required for you.

A silly example is here https://repl.it/@SiddharthShishu/IntrepidPunctualProspect

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = f2(x)
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that this would work if such values as zeroes, empty collections and other stuff which evaluate to False is NOT a valid value for y.